# What is the difference between named and anonymous functions in var declaration?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand how js parser works and wonder why there is no error in a declaration of **var a** below:

```
> var a = function b() {return 1;}
undefined
> typeof a
'function'
> typeof b
'undefined'
> function c() {return 1;}
undefined
> typeof c
'function'
> var d = function () {return 1;}
undefined
> typeof d
'function'
```

I think that:

- named function MUST be declared as **c()**,
- if you want to use function as var, you MUST declare it like **d**(use anonymous function)

I do not understand what is the difference between **var a** and **var d** declaration.

Can somebody tell me why function identifier is allowed in var declaration and what is the meaning of **b** in this case?

Comment: @JamesAllardice If you closely look at the question, this is not the dupe of that. However, this has been asked many times.

Comment: This was marked as a duplicate of another question, but that was asking about function expressions Vs function declarations, this is about named function expressions and anonymous function expressions.

Comment: The question that I chose does provide an answer to everything asked here, in the 2nd most upvoted answer (but not the accepted answer).